# Execute stored procedure from entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an asp.net core web API project, where I need to get result from a procedure. I am mapping procedure result with some model(TblUser, which is just a class with properties not a table in database). I am getting error that "TblUser is not an object", how to execute the procedure to get the result in a desired model.

Can we create some generic function where we can pass procedure inputs as well?

Edit: Here procedure is returning all mapping properties of model TblUser just TblUserId is not being returned.

```
    public List<TblUser> GetUsersServerSide(Filters filter)
    {
        List<TblUser> users = new List<TblUser>();
        users = null;
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new DBContext())
            {
                var SearchValue = new SqlParameter("@SearchValue", filter.SearchValue ?? "");
                var CurrentPageNumber = new SqlParameter("@PageNo", filter.CurrentPageNumber);
                var PageSize = new SqlParameter("@PageSize", filter.PageSize);
                var SortBy = new SqlParameter("@SortColumn", filter.SortBy);
                var SortDir = new SqlParameter("@SortOrder", filter.SortDir);
                users = db.TblUsers
                .FromSql("Exec dbo.GetUsers @SearchValue, @PageNo, @PageSize, @SortColumn, @SortOrder", SearchValue, CurrentPageNumber, PageSize, SortBy, SortDir).ToList();
            }
            return users;
        }

public class TblUser
{
    public int TblUserId { get; set; }        
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: All columns in the target table that map to properties on the entity must be included in the SQL statement.

Comment: Please include the complete Exception and indicate the statement causing it.

Comment: What is your stored procedure like?